# I want to add a number to a bytes array in solidity

Tags: arrays, byte, solidity, smartcontracts

So, i am writing a contract that converts a number to binary, and when i want to set the index of the array to a number, the compiler throws this error:

```
TypeError: Type bytes memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type bytes1
```

This is a example of the code that i am trying to do:

```
bytes memory _binary = new bytes(8);
uint r = 0;
//Loop and math
_binary[i] = abi.encodePacked(r);

return string(_binary);
```

The _binary line that is throwing the error, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`abi.encodePacked` returns the `bytes` type - a dynamic-length array of bytes.

But `_binary[i]` is a `bytes1` type - a fixed-length array of bytes with length 1. (It might be a bit confusing, there is no "single byte item", just an "array of one byte".)

So you need to typecast the value to `bytes1`:

```
_binary[i] = bytes1(abi.encodePacked(r));
```